# wp bakery plugin not working due to dokan plugin

Tags: wordpress, wpbakery

in my WordPress website i found that wpbakery page builder doesn't work correctly while Dokan plugin is enabled. for example when we add a text block, the editor is not loaded and sometime text block is not loaded at all. when we disable Dokan plugin, it works good.i cant deactivate dokan plugin which is important for me is it possible to correct such inconsistencies by altering any configuration files ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

There seems to be a problem going on with Dokan as acknowledged by the developer here around 5 hours ago - https://wordpress.org/support/topic/dokan-conflicts-with-wpbakery-page-builder/

As suggested by plugin dev from Dokan, you can just roll back to the Dokan v3.3.2 or v3.3.1 and that should resolve the issue temporarily. You can use any roll back plugin to find the older version of the Dokan lite plugin.

Stay updated to get a more robust solution by following the above link or contacting the Dokan support here - https://wedevs.com/contact

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: i solved my problem thankyou for your support.